# What is the value returned by following macro

Tags: c, linux-device-driver

What is the value returned by following macro if SNDRV_CARDS is equal to 8

```
#define SNDRV_DEFAULT_IDX  { [0 ... (SNDRV_CARDS-1)] = -1 }
```

I found this in a driver code.

Answer (score 2):

That's a [GNU extended designated initializer](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html).

The code the macro expands to is:

```
{ [0 ... (8-1)] = -1 }
```

which in turn is an array of 8 integers, all set to -1.